# Make a Recyclerview of 9 items with GridLayoutManager fit the screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bitmap, android-adapter

I have a Grid that was generated by a `RecyclerView` and GridLayoutManager , so in my case I will always have only 9 items on the Grid, so I want them to fill the entire screen. Below is how they look on my screen:

[image]

This is the `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then, the `single_item.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How I attached the Gridlayoutmanager :

```
        rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);        
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(allBitmaps, MainActivity.this);
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3);
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rv.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

So I want the grids to fit well the entire screen, how best can this be done ?

Comment: Fitting the screen will make them losing their aspect ratio

Comment: @Zain, would provide your solution for fitting the screen , we might resolve the aspect ration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the scenario:

- Measure the width & height of the `RecycerView` before attaching the adapter to it:
- Get the desired `RecyclerView` item width & height by dividing the width & height of the previous step by 3; as you have 3 items horizontally and vertically.
- Pass the item width & height to the `RecyclerView` adapter as parameters and store them as fields.

**In activity onCreate():**

```
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        if (recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
            recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        float width = (float) recyclerView.getWidth() / 3;
        float height = (float) recyclerView.getHeight() / 3;
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(context, width, height, allBitmaps);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return true;
    }
});
```

- Set the `ImageView` width & height in the `ViewHolder`:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemWidth;
        image.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemHeight;
    }
}
```

I tested this with just an `ImageView` as a list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Portrait preview:

[image]

Landscape preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked, is there a way of making all of them squares instead of triangles

Comment: I guess you mean instead of rectangles? If so, then they won't fit the entire layout as it's a rectangle and this is not what you want.

Comment: I didn't get it do you mean triangle item of the `Gridlayout`?

Comment: I don't why I keep on typing triangles , I meant **rectangle**. Apologies

Comment: No problem mate, I also dismissed it in the first comment :D .. if you need them squares then we need a square mobile set (or a square `RecyclerView` layout, so we'll back to the initial stage), I have two suggestion, first you can let them as-is like in your OP, but center the RecyclerView in the screen, and have a some blur background .. the second one is to cut the original image to fit the phone screen before dividing it into 9 pieces (I didn't test it, but it can have a distorted image).. Good luck in it anyways

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want those images to fill up the screen, you need to modify the width and height of the image inside your single item.xml